# вопрос по срезам

Tags: python

Всем привет! не могу понять как сделать срез с условием "или"
пример кода:

```
srez = line[line.find('-')+1:line.find('\')]
```

но в тексте, из которого нужно сделать срез, бывает что второе условие не символ '\' а символ '>'. как сделать проверку строки и на тот и на тот символ? уже все перепробовал, типа

```
srez = line[line.find('-')+1:line.find('\' or '>')]
```

итд

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Видимо, вам нужно это:

```
srez = line[line.find('-')+1: min(line.find('\\'), line.find('>'))]
```

Ищем индексы первых вхождений обоих символов и берём минимальный. Правда, это будем работать, если есть оба символа, т.к. если функция `find` не найдёт символ, она вернёт `-1`.

Если учесть, что символа `'\'` или `'>'` может не быть, выходит как-то так:

```
ind1 = line.find('\\')
ind2 = line.find('>')
res_ind = ind1 if ind1 < ind2 and ind1 >= 0 or ind2 == - 1 else ind2
# srez = line[line.find('-') + 1: ind1 if ind1 < ind2 and ind1 >= 0 or ind2 == - 1 else ind2]
srez = line[line.find('-') + 1: res_ind]
print(srez)
```

Можно с помощью регулярных выражений:

```
import re
line = ...
srez = line[line.find('-') + 1: re.search(r'\\|>', line).start()]
```

Comment: нет, символ есть точно

Comment: символ есть один из двух. а если в переменной с помощью or как то попробовать поставить \ or >? не сработает? просто пока не дома, не могу проверить

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Может быть такой вариант подойдет (без использования регулярных выражений):

`start = line.find('-')
end = line.find('>') if '>' in line else line.find('\\')
srez = line[start + 1:end]`

Разбит на несколько строк для того, чтобы удобнее было читать